# Click submit button to reveal form, then click again to send form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

This is the interaction I am after..

1. User clicks on the search link.
2. Search input slides open.
3. Once open, the search link turns into the form submit button, and sends the form.

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/fmHIh).

My code...

HTML

```
<div class="searchB">
<form action="/search-results/">
  <span class="i-search"></span>
    <input class="srchType" type="search" name="q" placeholder="e.g type here...">
    <input class="srchGo" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.searchB {
float: left;
padding-top: $baseline/3;
}

.searchB span { 
font-size: 1.3em;
}

.srchType {
display: none;
background-color: #fff;
border:none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.srchGo {
background-color: #fff;
border: none;
cursor:pointer; 
}
```

JS

```
$('.srchGo').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 $('.srchType').show('slide');
});
```

I would also like to know how I can integrate it so as soon as the user starts typing, the search link adds a class of Bold text (indicating search link is now clickable)

I am currently at step 2 but cannot think how to integrate the submit link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a flag to see if the button was already clicked or not :

```
$('.srchGo').on('click', function(e){

    if ( ! $(this).data('clicked') ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.srchType').show('slide');
    }

    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

for the bold links, something like :

```
$('.srchType').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.some_class_for_links').css('font-weight','bold');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.srchGo').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if($(this).val()=='GO')
     //dosearch
    alert('search');
else
    $('.srchType').toggle('slide');
});
$('.srchType').keyup(function() {
   if($(this).val()!='')
     $('.srchGo').val('GO');
   else
     $('.srchGo').val('SEARCH');
})
```